# Optimizing through a Transition matrix, in a non-stepwise manner

Tags: python, algorithm, probability

I made some sort of a transition matrix of an increase in probability of success, given the allocation of some finite resource (e.g. 4 in this case):

```
            inc1     inc2      inc3      inc4  

option1    0.0000   0.0000    0.3021    0.1541 
option2    0.1000   0.0100    0.0010    0.0001 
option3    0.2000   0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

At this moment, I consider the allocation in a stepwise manner. That is, for every +1 increase, I just check which option maximizes payout. Generally, the more I add to one option, the lower the increase will become (thus opening the window for other options).

However, I noticed that sometimes it gets stuck: if only I'd be willing to allow for 0 increase for sometime, I could get an amazing increase.

How can I maximize the increase by not just looking in a stepwise fashion, but considering it as a whole?

Note that stepwise would go like this:

```
     option3 -> option2 -> option2 -> option2 = 0.311
```

whereas the optimal solution here is:

```
     option3 -> option1 -> option1 -> option1 = 0.5021
```

Also note that this is a simple case and there are more options and different payouts. Therefore, answers just considering this specific problem, and which do not generalize, are useless.

**What would be your approach to this problem?**

---

---

Note: I think it will be a problem with at most 20 options and the total sum to allocate might be 25. I'm looking for an efficient implementation, or just some general tricks not to have to consider every single combination.

Note 2: I tagged it with Python as I will implement it there, though I'm mostly just looking for CS advice I guess.

Comment: Explain me smth, if I'm in option1 and inc1, which option and inc I can visit next? I'm pretty sure that this problem can be solved using dynamic programming, but I can get deeper in details because I don't undesrtand your examples

Comment: @Ralor Ok. In the start, you can visit only `inc1`, from any option. As you pick one option, you progress in that branch, and you will be able to use `inc2` in that branch (while the other options are still in `inc1`). Similarly, you can only go to `inc4` when `inc1`, `inc2`, and `inc3` were all chosen for that same option.

Comment: I got it, I'll try to solve it now.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic programming will be quick and simple. For i from 0 to m, the number of rows, determine for the first i rows how best to allocate k steps (from 0 to n). To go from i rows to i + 1, we try all possible divisions of steps between the first i rows and row i + 1 (j is the number allocated to i + 1) and take the best.

Python sample:

```
def optimize(matrix, steps):
    best = {j: (0, ()) for j in range(steps + 1)}
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        bestprime = best.copy()
        p = 0
        for j, pj in enumerate(row):
            if pj == 0: continue
            p += pj
            for k in range(j + 1, steps + 1):
                bestprime[k] = max(bestprime[k],
                                   (best[k - j - 1][0] + p,
                                    best[k - j - 1][1] + (i + 1,) * (j + 1)))
        best = bestprime
    return bestprime[steps]

>>> optimize([[0  , 0   , 0.3021, 0.1541],
...           [0.1, 0.01, 0.001 , 0.0001],
...           [0.2, 0   , 0     , 0     ]], 4)
(0.5021, (1, 1, 1, 3))
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to not append a step when the step is equal to 0 (meaning that all subsequent increases will be 0)?

Comment: @PascalvKooten I believe that the line `if pj == 0` will do the trick.

Comment: Extending the steps to 1000 yields `(0.6131, (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))`. When you add a 0 to each row and set steps to 1000, it yields `(0.7673, (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3))`

Comment: Case: `optimize([[0, 0, 0.3021, 0.1541, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], steps=5)` should return the same as `optimize([[0, 0, 0.3021, 0.1541, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], steps=4)`; not advising an option when the option yields 0.

Comment: @PascalvKooten I fixed an off-by-one error in rev 3.

Answer (score 1):

So, I came up with a different answer. Not sure how it scales (EDIT: REALLY WELL, apparently. It did a 10,000x10,000 matrix with 100 steps in 6.4s), but, it's interesting. :)

```
import copy
import random
import timingdecorator as timeit

test1 = [[0,0,.3021,.1541],
        [.1,.01,.001,.0001],
        [.2,0,0,0]]

test2 = [[.2,0,1.9,.4],
        [.6,0,0,0],
        [.2,0,.1,0]]


test3 = [ [ random.random() for x in xrange(10) ] for i in xrange(10) ]

def findmaxspot(matrix):
    mx = -1
    spot = (0,0)
    for rindex,row in enumerate(matrix):
        for vindex,val in enumerate(row):
            if val>mx:   # hmm... ties... issue?
                mx = val
                spot = (rindex,vindex+1)
    return (mx,spot)

def efficiency(row):
    return [ float(sum(row[:i+1]))/(i+1) for i,val in enumerate(row) ]

@timeit.timeit
def optimize(tm,steps,checksteps=False):
    r = 0
    matrix = [ row[:steps] for row in tm ]
    choices = []
    m = [ efficiency(row) for row in matrix ]
    # print m
    while steps:
        if checksteps:
            if not any(m):
                return (r,choices)
        choice = findmaxspot(m)
        if choice[0]==0:
            return (r,choices)
        steps -= choice[1][1]
        r += sum(matrix[choice[1][0]][:choice[1][1]])
        for x in xrange(choice[1][1]):
            choices.append(choice[1][0])
        for index, row in enumerate(matrix):
            if index==choice[1][0]:
                matrix[index] = matrix[index][choice[1][1]:]
                m[index] = efficiency(matrix[index])
            else:
                matrix[index] = matrix[index][:steps]
                m[index] = m[index][:steps]
        # print (choice,m)
    return (r,choices)
```

So, it works by first computing a matrix with the average return per step. Obviously, the 3rd option wins by a longshot in the first step. Then, it removes the taken options (I assume this is a valid constraint and you can't take the third option 4 times) and prunes all unreachable points. Then it reconstructs the efficiency matrix, finding that the next is the first option, so we take those!

I *think* it always finds the optimal solution, but I'm not sure. Let me know if you find a counter-case. I'd actually be interested in testing it on the full dataset, if you'd be willing to send it to me. :)

EDIT3: **It should be noted that the order of the moves returned is also the most efficient ordering.** That is, if interrupted at any point, my solution will still be optimal. If I plan to invest 9 steps but get interrupted at 6, I will have simply invested in the optimal way for 6 steps. David's, however, will likely be suboptimal since his is sorted numerically, not by priority.

EDIT: I realized that I actually only needed to recompute the efficiency for rows in which I prune from the beginning, so we only need to recompute one row at a time.

EDIT2: Also, drastically increased performance for large matrices by pruning at the beginning. If you test mine vs. David's solution, mine took 6.4s for the 10k x 10k Matrix with 100 steps, while his took 32.6s.

Comment: It would actually be used in a game of Risk (Warlight), for which I calculated the probabilities of a successful attack for many, many battles. Using the information of probability gain when I would consider placing reinforcements, I can optimize the placement of troops by looking which combination will yield the highest probability increase. In other words: I don't really have a data set, I just plan to use it in future cases.

Comment: Ah, I first thought your answer might be wrong, but it does not give back the "correct" ordering (though still the good result)? Luckily the order is not important.

Comment: It's also completely breaking when you ask for more steps than possible.

Comment: Furthermore, it cannot handle integers (it yielded the wrong result)

Comment: Also, it still returns those cases where the probability increase is 0, I would prefer to skip those (David solved it).

Comment: It actually gives back a better ordering than David's. Mine gives the order of what is most efficient first, or what you should prioritize. And yes, it might break for more steps than possible. I'm not too concerned about that, frankly. Also, for integers, it's likely having rounding error. Stick a float around the sum and it should go away. I'll add that. Though, what exactly do you mean by the probability increase of 0?

Comment: *"what exactly do you mean by the probability increase of 0"* -- when not enough non-zeros occur in the transition matrix, the algorithm considers the zeros. Since I plan to use this in multiple cases in a row, I'd like it to remove when the increase is 0 (such that some steps can still be considered when using a new matrix).

Comment: Updated. Should have fixed the more-steps-than-possible issue (with an optional flag) and the integer issue.

Comment: Ahhh. Fixed. Now if the remaining max's are 0, it returns.

Comment: What does this do for `[[0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4.5]]` with five steps?

Comment: The third option 4 times. Exact output is [2,2,2,2] (zero indexed).

Comment: Also, @PascalvKooten, I'd like to see an example of your method in action. I can give you my e-mail if you have the time.

Comment: @PascalvKooten, drop me a line at `logan.neal.collins` at `gmail.com`. Also, I'd appreciate it if you accepted an answer between us.